# Implement a custom feedback form into magento

Tags: php, forms, magento, customization

Can someone please help me with implementing a customized form into Magento?

I have created a PHP form that works outside Magento that collects user data and allows them to upload a file. I am clueless as to how to get this functioning in the Magento environment.  We are already taking advantage of the internal form with a contact us.  This one is a feedback form to collect user data.

I have been digging around in Google for a couple of hours now and the only scenarios are how to get aspects of their forms working, not how they got it in there in the first place.

Your responses are appreciated.  I am even open to you just giving me the right link to look at.

Comment: Well since I posted this almost an hour ago I went with the obvious and copied the contact form we are currently using into a second page and set that up in Magento admin under cms/pages.  I am going through now and creating the fields.  

Next question is what to I edit after this so the form gets processed?  This is going to go to a separate email address.

Lastly - the form will need the ability to upload a file, any ideas on what the syntax is for that?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article about how to create a custom form in magento: [Create custom form](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/).
It describes how to create a route in `config.xml`, how to create the controller php (where you can handle the *post action*), and an example of the template file.

Comment: Great, thank you.  I have been bumped to another project this week but will refer back to this once I get that one done.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: hi peter, i have same issue, my feedback from : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0 how can i display in  all pages of my site including home page?                                          @Peter